# Custom transition between view controllers in ios6

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios6

I have a transition class that has two views in the same view controller. This works ok. I want to apply the same transition to a second view controller. I'm not getting any exceptions, but it isn't working...

The current transition code is like this:

Custom Transition class

```
- (id)initWithBaseView:(UIView *)baseView firstView:(UIView *)firstView lastView:(UIView *)lastView
{
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.view = baseView;
        self.originalView = firstView;
        self.nextView = lastView;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is the code that is working:

Single View Controller class

```
- (IBAction)doTransition:(id)sender
{
    MyTransition *transition = [[MyTransition alloc] initWithBaseView:self.view 
                                                                          firstView:self.currentView 
                                                                           lastView:self.nextView];
    [transition buildAnimation];
}
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
- (IBAction)doTransition:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    MyTransition *transition = [[MyTransition alloc] initWithBaseView:self.view
                                                                          firstView:self.currentView 
                                                                           lastView:secondView.lastView];
    [transition buildAnimation];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [super viewDidLoad];
    secondView = [[SecondViewController *) secondView initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
}
```

where First View is in the firstView Controller and next view is in the second view controller..

UPDATE:

I've updated the First VC as follows:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
        [super viewDidLoad];
        secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

- (IBAction)doTransition:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    MyTransition *transition = [[MyTransition alloc] initWithBaseView:self.view                                             firstView:self.currentView                                                   lastView:secondView.view];

    [transition buildAnimation];
}
```

Logging the second VC shows that it is not called..

Comment: Chris clearly answered your question. It is pretty uncool of you to mark your own answer as correct after setting a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work if you try something like this:

```
- (IBAction)doTransition:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    MyTransition *transition = [[MyTransition alloc] initWithBaseView:self.view
                                                                          firstView:self.currentView 
                                                                           lastView:secondView.view];
    [transition buildAnimation];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [super viewDidLoad];
    secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
}
```

If i understand what you're trying to do, then you should be able to perform the same animation on the SecondViewController's view, just like you would with a regular view. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for answering. I still get the transition ending with the first view. Logging shows that the second VC is not called.

Comment: I've also tried initializing the second VC within the first, and linking it's view value.. But that returns null. I've updated the question to show this code.. The second VC does not even init/load so I must be doing something dumb.

Comment: Well, this: `secondView = [(SecondViewController *) secondView initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];` is not right.

It should be `secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];` Try that out

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that I was not initializing the secondView correctly in its own ViewController. Once I did that, the transition worked as needed.

For others, the code I used was as follows:

FirstViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [super viewDidLoad];

    secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

}

- (IBAction)clickOpenDoor:(id)sender
{

MyTransition *transition = [[MyTransition alloc] initWithBaseView:self.view
firstView:self.currentView                                               lastView:secondView.view];

    [transition buildAnimation];
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 500)];
        tableView  = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 500)];
        [view addSubview:tableView];
    }
```

Comment: It seems like chris answered this question 16 hours ago. Why would you post a lesser version of his answer and then select it as a solution?

Comment: Well, Chris's answer didn't work, but he did get me thinking, so I have no problem crediting him with the answer.

Comment: @D.Tran - It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question with an approach that worked for you, even if there's a bounty involved. You've lost the reputation you put up for the bounty anyways, so there's no benefit to yourself to award the bounty to your own answer.

Comment: For my part, I hurried off a solution this morning that as D.Tran said, was less of an answer than Chris's. I have added the code that worked for me.